# How to uncombine taskbar buttons and be able to move them separably in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I used the Windows taskbar setting to never combine taskbar buttons. However, when I move one of the buttons of the same app, the rest of the buttons of the same app move along with it, which I don't want to happen.
I used to use 7+ Taskbar Tweaker and it did the job but my company introduced an antimalware app that blocks 7+ Taskbar Tweaker from running.

Is there a way to be able to move the buttons separately? I assume 7+ Taskbar Tweaker is using some registry setting to enable this functionality? Does anyone know what the setting is?
The source code for the app is on Github so I might be looking at the code and learn how it's done.

Comment: duplicate: [How to fix Windows 10's taskbar item ordering?](https://superuser.com/q/1323291/241386)

Comment: @phuclv That other question doesn't have an answer and the posted answer is more like a discussion than a real answer. I don't consider it a duplicate.